# From monthly table to daily table in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud

I tried to disaggregate a monthly table into daily tables to improve performance. Let's assume I have the following schema of n rows:

```
field1  STRING  NULLABLE    
field2  STRING  NULLABLE    
field3  RECORD  NULLABLE    
field4  STRING  REPEATED    
field5  STRING  REPEATED    
field5  STRING  REPEATED    
field6  STRING  NULLABLE
.
.
.
.
fieldn  STRING  REPEATED
```

I tried to create the tables with the Web UI, querying the data per day, saving the results into another table (the daily table) [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#largequeryresults). But I have many  `REPEATED` columns, so I had to `FLATTEN` the table.

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM (
    FLATTEN((
      SELECT
        ...
      FROM (
          FLATTEN((
            SELECT
              ...
            FROM
              table),
            field3)
          )
        ),
      f4)
    )
  )
```

I don't want to create multiple records per repeated column, I want to conserve the schema and info of the monthly table. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: It is not clear what have you tried so far!? Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: maybe you'd like to migrate to partitioned tables: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables

Comment: @FelipeHoffa do you know how to set the date of the partition from an already existing column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Web UI - to preserve schema - you should  do below

1. Click "Show Options"

for Legacy SQL

2. Set table
3. Check "Allow Large Results" checkbox
4. Uncheck "Flatten Result" checkbox

for Standard SQL

2. Set table
3. uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" checkbox

Then, you should use below :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE <condition to filter given day rows>
```